# Avoid recursion for this functionality

Tags: c++, algorithm

My code looks as follows,

```
myParent = curreObj->getmyParent();
if(myParent != NULL && myParent->getAttrib() != "abc")
    myParent=myParent->getmyParent();
return myParent;
```

Important note: the property "abc" can be held by many people. It is not a 1-1 property. So, maintaining a map might not be possible. And also I want it in my lineage. So, if I maintain a multimap, from the property I would have a list of objects through which I would have to loop to get to my object which would make it a O(n) operation. I am trying to get it less than O(n), ideally to O(1), if not to O(log n) atleast. Is there a solution?

I want to get my ancestor that had the property equal to a certain value. If not, return NULL.

I am using Visual Studio 2013, C++.

The code above does it, but I would like to do it better, atleast avoid recursion.

Is there a way I can do it? Is there a data structure I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: `this functionality`/`My code looks` code to achieve _what_? (Put `get [an/the nearest] ancestor [satisfying some predicate]` more prominently: title, first sentence, name of a/the procedure.) `avoid recursion` in my book, _recursion_ reads _directly or indirectly more instances of the same_: I don't see that in your question. (What is `lineage`?)

Answer (score 2):

You could store pointer to the parent in your object and then do this  :-

```
myParent = curreObj->parent;
while(myParent != NULL && myParent->getAttrib() != "abc")
    myParent=myParent->parent;
```

Comment: This saves the recursion, but still is O(n). Maybe I want to get to O(1)? Is that possible?

Comment: No, You will have to loop over all parents to check the while condition.

Answer (score 0):

O(n) is not possible unless you do a pre-processing and save all the information in some data structure.

Also I would assume the n in O(n) refers to the length between the curreObj and its farthest ancestor. If n is the number of all nodes of "curreObj" and you are using a binary tree for saving the relationship, you should have already achieved O(log n).

If you still want to improve the efficiency by saving some extra data in a pre-processing step, I would suggest you to have a embedded hash map in a hashmap, so for each key, there might be a hashmap stored as the value and in this hashmap the hash of the object references will be the key and the object itself will be the value.

I haven't worked on C++ for many years, so please forgive me for the wrong syntax, this is just pseudocode.

```
HashMap<string, HashMap<string, Object>> map;

// it should be the value you specify
HashMap<string, Object> embeddedMap = map.get("abc"); 
embeddedMap.get(curreObj.hash())
```

To create this map, you need to loop over all your nodes and save them with the property and the corresponding "parent", it should be something like,

```
HashMap<string, HashMap<string, Object>> map;

myParent = curreObj->getmyParent();
if(myParent != NULL && myParent->getAttrib() != null){
    HashMap<string, Object> embeddedMap;
    embeddedMap.put(curreObj.hash(),myParent);
    map.put(myParent->getAttrib(), embeddedMap);
}
```

In this way, you can retrieve the value in O(1), but you will have to save all the extra info in O(n2).

Hope I understand your question correctly and this can give you some inspiration.